# How to reroute SFTP traffic via NGINX

Tags: nginx, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to setup an FTP subdomain, such that all incoming SFTP requests to (say) ftp.myname.com, get routed to a particular internal server, (say) 10.123.456 via port 22.

How do I use nginx to route this traffic?

I've already setup the SFTP server, and can SFTP directly to the server, say:

sftp username@123.456.7890, which works fine.

The problem is that when I setup nginx to route all traffic to ftp.myname.com, it connects, but the passwords get rejected. I have no problems routing web traffic to my other subdomains, say dev.myname.com (with passwords), but it doesn't work for the SFTP traffic:

```
server {
    listen 22;
    server_name ftp.myname.com;
    return .............
}
```

How do I define the return sting to route the traffic with the passwords?

The connection is SFTP (via port 22).

Thanks

Comment: just a note: sftp uses ssh-server to connect to. If you define nginx to listen to port 22, it expects a http / https connection to this port. In my personal opinion you cannot forward a sftp request send to nginx to ssh-server. check what ports your services listen to, so ssh-server (for sftp connections) might already listen on port22 to accept connections. you might restrict connections to port 22 via ufw. To get a special subdomain to listen only to port 22, someone else might help out.

Answer (score 1):

Aswering to @peixotorms: yes, you can.  nginx can proxy/load balance http as well as tcp and udp traffic, see nginx stream modules documentation (at the [nginx main documentation page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/)) , and specifically the [stream core module's documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html).

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do this on nginx (http only), you must use something like HaProxy and a simple dns record for your subdomain pointing to the server ip.

Some info: http://jpmorris-iso.blogspot.pt/2013/01/load-balancing-openssh-sftp-with-haproxy.html

Edit:

Since nginx version 1.15.2 it's now possible to do that using the variable $ssl_preread_protocol. The official blog added post about how to use this variable for multiplexing HTTPS and SSH on the same port.
https://www.nginx.com/blog/running-non-ssl-protocols-over-ssl-port-nginx-1-15-2/

Example of configuring SSH on an upstream block:

```
stream {
    upstream ssh {
        server 192.0.2.1:22;
    }

    upstream sslweb {
        server 192.0.2.2:443;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
        default ssh;
        "TLSv1.2" sslweb;
    }

    # SSH and SSL on the same port
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to have a combination SSH, HTTPS and HTTP ? can i achieve with ssl_preread all three?